# Smartcvs error: Authentication Failed, You could not get authenticated by the CVS-server

Tags: authentication, cvs

I am trying to connect from a windows computer to a ubuntu linux server, It is about cvs, I want to do a checkout. I use smartcvs 7.1.9.

I get this error when I try to connect to the server: (Project > Checkout >  Next)

> Authentication Failed: You could not get authenticated by the
>   CVS-server. Details: I/O-Exception: Failed to negotiate a transport
>   component [diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1]
>   [diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]

Anybody ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

This is a cvs server issue.
SmartCVS uses the diffie-hellman key exchange method for authentication which is known to have security issues. Therefore it has been disabled by default in current standard openssh(d) server configurations.

If you know what you are doing and don't care about the security implications, just add the following lines to sshd_config:

## starts here

KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1

Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,blowfish-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc

## ends here

If you're on linux.. recreate the keys and restart the opensshd service:

## dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server

## /etc/init.d/ssh restart

Regards
Erwin